# Java ISBN formatting

Tags: java

I am trying to write a program that read's an inventory file of books and produces an inventory report that is written to the screen. I am having trouble trying to format the ISBN number. The ISBN in the input file is given as a 10 digit sequence(Ex: 0321479270). For the reports I need to reformat it with a pattern of 1-3-5-1 digits(Ex 0-321-479270).

Here is what I have so far...

```
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;

public class Inventory
{
    public static void main(String[] args)throws IOException 
    {

        //Vaiable declartions 
        int edition, quanity;
        double pricePerBook;
        String isbn, author, title, publisher;

        //Open the file and set delimiters
        File file = new File("inventory.txt");
        Scanner inputFile = new Scanner(file);
        inputFile.useDelimiter("_|/|\\r?\\n");

        //Read from the file
        while (inputFile.hasNext())
        {
            isbn = inputFile.next();
            author = inputFile.next();
            title = inputFile.next();
            edition = inputFile.nextInt();
            publisher = inputFile.next();
            quanity = inputFile.nextInt();
            pricePerBook = inputFile.nextDouble();
            System.out.printf("%s" /* %s %s %d %s %d %f "*/, formatISBN(isbn)); //, author, title, edition, publisher, quanity, pricePerBook);
        }

        //Close the flie
        inputFile.close();
    }

    //ISBN Method
    public static String formatISBN(String isbn)
    {
        if (isbn.length() == 1)
        {
            isbn += -;
            return isbn;
        }
    }
}
```

So I'm having trouble in the ISBN method, I can't seem to figure out how to print the ISBN with the "-".

Comment: I think the best option for you is to use String.format and select you input using subString methods. Simple, but ok

Comment: Note that not all ISBNs use the format 1-3-5-1. The publisher ID (second value) has variable width, which means the title ID (third value) also has variable width.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's easiest just to extract substrings:

```
return String.format("%s-%s-%s-%s",
                     isbn.substring(0, 0 + 1),
                     isbn.substring(1, 1 + 3),
                     isbn.substring(4, 4 + 5),
                     isbn.substring(9, 9 + 1));
```

Comment: THANK YOU SO MUCH!

Answer (score 2):

You could use a regular expression:

```
return isbn.replaceAll("(\\d)(\\d{3})(\\d{5})(\\d)", "$1-$2-$3-$4");
```

Answer (score 0):

Or using StringBuilder:

```
StringBuilder result = new StringBuilder();
StringBuilder stringBuilder = new StringBuilder("0321479270");
result.append(stringBuilder.charAt(0));
result.append("-");
result.append(stringBuilder.substring(1,3));
result.append("-");
result.append(stringBuilder.substring(4));
return result.toString();
```

Remember that this only works if the isbn is well formatted.

Comment: If you are using `StringBuilder`, you don't actually need to explicitly create substrings: `result.append(str, 1, 3)`. Also, you don't need `stringBuilder` here, just use the string directly.

Comment: Agree. I normally use StringBuilder rater than String for performance. But yes, the ISBN is already a String, so it's easier just to use it.

Comment: If you wrote this as direct concatenation, the compiler would rewrite it to use a StringBuilder: you are simply making the source code harder to read. And the second StringBuilder is unnecessary here, and likely reduces performance.